# How to get the filenames of all the php files which generates a webpage?

Tags: php

Suppose we have a website at the url http://www.example.com/page/

But that page is generated by many php files (eg. as in Wordpress, index.php, header.php, content.php, footer.php)

How can I get all the filenames and their paths that are required to generate that page? (eg. index.php content.php as in WP)?

For instance, as in Wordpress, different pages will use different themes that are generated from different php files. You have to sift through those files one by one. So my question is how I can do it quickly and programmatically.

Thank you

Comment: you need to check manually in code I think there is no way other than this.

Comment: you open the php page, you search for include,require_once and you note the params of those functions

Comment: In case of PHP, use `__DIR__` and `__FILE__`...

Comment: Difficult. For instance, as in Wordpress, different pages will use different themes that are generated from different php files. You have to sift through those files one by one. So my question is how I can do it quickly and programmatically.

Comment: You could probably use something like xdebug to profile the files that are loaded.

Comment: There was functions in php get_included_files and get_required_files you can bulid logic based on this. But i guess still this was not a perfect solution.

Comment: Added complexity if you want to know all the resource files also like images, css, javascript etc

Answer (score 1):

If the page(s) code doesn't stop execution using `exit`, you could potentially use the `php.ini` directive [`auto_append_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) in conjunction with [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php). At that point, it would be a matter of how you track what page was viewed, and if you display additional information on the page or log to a text file, etc.